# How to pass seeded image data into Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seeded my Rails db with the following for Posts: title, description, body, and image. For image I used data in the assets. So for example in the seed file I have:

```
post_image: '/images/main.image.jpg'
```

I'm able to hit all the other data in the views doing the typical:

```
<%= post.title %>
```

How do I pull in the image? I've tried the following to no avail:

- <%= asset_path('post.post_image')%>. Nothing appears
- <%= asset_url('post.post_image')%>. I get http://localhost:3000/post.main.image.jpg
- <%= image_tag('post.post_image')%>. I get a small icon with Post next to it but not a full image.
- <%= image_tag @post_image%>. I get a small icon but not a full image.
- <%= image_alt(post.post_image) %>. I get at main.image.jpg present

Did I seed incorrectly or am I just using the wrong helper to get the image?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I seeded incorrectly. Image_tag will hit images under the asset pipeline. Did a db:reset after I fixed the seed file to just be: post_image: 'main.image.jpg'. Correct code is:

```
<%= image_tag post.post_image %>
```